# Can I perfectly clone any ordinary object?

Tags: javascript, object, internals

I want to write a `cloneDeep` function that clones any JS object. There are two distinct problems here:

1. Self references.
2. Exotic objects.

I want to focus on the latter. Exotic objects in ECMAScript are listed in this section: [10.4 Built-in Exotic Object Internal Methods and Slots](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-built-in-exotic-object-internal-methods-and-slots). There, it mentions exotic objects like strings, bound functions, Arrays etc. Specifically, it does not mention `RegExp`.

So, my expectation was that given `RegExp` is an ordinary object, if I copy all its own properties (enumerable and non-enumerable) and its prototype, it will behave like the source `RegExp` object. But that is not true: it fails when I try to access the getter `regex.source` by explicitly saying it is not a `RegExp` object.

Digging further, I found that some user-inaccessible internal slots exist in ECMAScript for various objects only to be accessible through their constructors.

This leads me to believe either of the two is true:

1. `RegExp` is also an exotic object somehow.
2. It is an ordinary object but there is some other state I did not copy.

Which one of these is true? Because I am not able to wrap my head around an ordinary object with object-specific internal slots.

Comment: how do you plan to copy arbitrary non-enumerable properties, exactly?

Comment: Anyway, _why are you doing this_? I can understand a need to clone POJOs (simple `object` types with only specifically-assigned value-properties with no constructors nor prototypes) but there simply isn't a need to clone _every_ object in JS, nethertheless as you've discovered it is _impossible_ for userland JS to clone many (or even most?) environment-provided objects like `RegExp` - I think you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is an *ordinary object* with some internal state that you could not copy.

Being an *exotic object* only means that it has some extraordinary implementation of the internal methods, not that it doesn't have any internal slots. Many builtin functions - such as the `.source` getter you describe - still require being called on an object with specific internal slots.